# Chrome libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed

Tags: google-chrome

When I try start Google-chrome I get the following error:

```
$ google-chrome
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
[39191:39191:0302/155530.651497:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[39148:39148:0302/155531.535909:ERROR:system_web_app_manager.cc(320)] Exceeded SWA install retry attempts.  Skipping installation, will retry on next OS update or when locale changes.
[39148:39148:0302/155531.592952:ERROR:system_web_app_manager.cc(320)] Exceeded SWA install retry attempts.  Skipping installation, will retry on next OS update or when locale changes.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Until yesterday it worked fine. Might something have damaged a file on my hard dive (i.e. iHD_drv_video.so)? The command `vainfo` gives the same init failed error on iHD_drv_video.so.

(sorry for the double post to Ubuntuforums, I'm puling my hairs out on why I get the error)

Answer (score 7):

You have to reinstall the [corresponding package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=dri%2FiHD_drv_video.so) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall intel-media-va-driver:amd64
```

then reboot, run `vainfo` for debug and `google-chrome` to test it.

If issue persists you have to reinstall all Intel-related packages by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i intel | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I reinstalled all the Intel related packages but that did not get rid of the errors in `vainfo`. Google-chrome also gives the _libva_ error (and crashes like a led Zeppelin).


Would you agree that one or more files on my computer was probably damaged? And that I should buy a new hard drive?

Comment: GNOME Disks can give some SMART information about your drive. You can check your file-system by forcing `fsck` on `/`. Also I would recommend to install and run `debsums` to check system integrity - `sudo apt-get install debsums` ; `sudo debsums_init`; `sudo debsums --changed --silent` .

Comment: Thanks for the `debsums` tip. It completed without serious errors or warnings... My other old Linux installation doesn't have VA stuff. Might `Google-chrome`'s crash be because of something else?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

1. The VA error. The command `vainfo` echoed an error on a VA driver (iHD_drv_video.so) I don't need ([link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/va-api-driver-broken/30529)):

```
$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop - 2.4.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

One needs to remove the package `intel-media-driver` this also uninstalls the meta-package (i.e. does nothing) `va-driver-all`. The proper VA driver for my Intel video chip (GPU) is `i965-va-driver`, that is: the one does not give an error in `vainfo`. I uninstalled it by temporarily disabling the repo's for 'Proprietary Drivers' and 'Software restricted by copyright' in Synaptic. Else: you get a forced installation of intel-media-driver-non-free.

2. This still did not solve my problems with Chrome. I had to backup my Bookmarks and delete `/home/my_name/.config/google-chrome/`, restart Chrome, make a new profile and copy my Bookmarks into the proper profile folder. Had to re-install my favourite Extensions. Done.

The VA error probably did **not** crash Chrome. I may have shut down my PC without properly closing Chrome, or my hard drive is getting old and breaking files. Will do a HDD check.

Thanks for the help all. :)